# Seed user after dropping table

Tags: seed

Thanks for your post!

I'm at the early stage of development of my project... and I do believe that the testing will be easier if I drop / re-create my db every time load my project. (using DropCreateDatabaseAlways in my seed)

The problem is that "users management" tables are only created after registering the first user (AccountController/Register)... and I cant figure out how to call that function from my seed...

Not sure if it's the correct approach if I want to create users with missing tables?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: in what language are you doing this??

Comment: What the hell are you talking about?